# Выполнение команд из другого файла

Tags: node.js, бот

Доброе время суток, Задался вопрос, Допустим есть файл app.js и command.js
app будет являться скелетом а command будет файлом с командами
Как мне из скелета вызвать команду?
Что-то подобие модулей

-app.js
-modules

- app.js ------|
- modules <-| --|
- command.js <-|

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Node js [require](https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/2.1.php)

Comment: Не подойдёт так как я пытаюсь вызвать команду из другого файла, функция тоже не прокатит так как записываются команды как есть а из app.js нужно вызвать её (Как вырвать слово из одного текста  и вставить в другой текст)

Comment: Допустим в command лежит команда получения id пользователя, из app мы пытаемся вызвать эту команду

Comment: в app.js нужно добавить обработчик аргументов запуска из command line (https://www.npmjs.com/package/meow, https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) и в коде программы просто пройтись по известным аргументам и выполнить сценарии